# Building schema validation definition for custom XML

Tags: xml, validation, schema

I have some problems in writing down the schema of my XML file, that is pretty simple.

As suggested me, I try to put other code (I removed that because I couldn't undestrand if I was messing up everything or not...):

I cannot figure out where is the problem of my schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0"
      standalone="yes"?>
<ChangeHistory xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <xs:schema id="ChangeHistory"
             xmlns=""
             xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="ChangeHistory"
                msdata:IsDataSet="true"
                msdata:MainDataTable="Version"
                msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:element name="Versions">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="Version">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="Edits">
                    <xs:complexType>
                      <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Edit">
                          <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:attribute name="Content" type="xs:string" />
                          </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                      </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                  </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:string" />
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <Versions>
    <Version Id="1.0.5 - Coming next!">
      <Edits>
        <Edit Content="Bla bla 1" />
        <Edit Content="Bla bla bla" />
      </Edits>
    </Version>
    <Version Id="1.0.4 - Coming soon!">
      <Edits>
        <Edit Content="First edit of the version" />
        <Edit Content="Second edit of the version" />
      </Edits>
    </Version>
  </Versions>
</ChangeHistory>
```

This XML is generated from a .NET DataSet, and I think the problem is inside (so the outside part is correct!) this element:

```
<xs:schema id="ChangeHistory"
    xmlns=""
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
```

All the attributes of **Version** and **Edit** elements are of type `xs:string`.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Uh why are your XML and schema in the same document?

Comment: Because this is an XML loaded as localized resource of my project, and Visual Studio can validate my XML during compilation...if I specify a correct schema!

Comment: I dont see element Edits in schema...

Comment: Yes, this is true: I was messing with upper elements...I think I can manage this problem if I solve the Version element problem!

Comment: Man, both your Versions and Edits elements do not appear in the schema, that is why things are failing. And I dont mean Version and Edit tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use this schema, as generated from the Visual Studio 20120 XSD tool:

```
<xs:schema id="ChangeHistory"
         xmlns=""
         xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
<xs:element name="ChangeHistory"
            msdata:IsDataSet="true"
            msdata:MainDataTable="Version"
            msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0"
               maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="Versions">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Version"
                        minOccurs="0"
                        maxOccurs="unbounded">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="Edits"
                              minOccurs="0"
                              maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                      <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Edit"
                                    minOccurs="0"
                                    maxOccurs="unbounded">
                          <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:attribute name="Content"
                                          type="xs:string" />
                          </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                      </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                  </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:attribute name="Id"
                              type="xs:string" />
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```